# Eliminate Nulls

Tags: json, powershell

I'm out of luck finding information...

This powershell script collecting cert info in LocalMachine:

```
$cert_days = get-childitem cert:LocalMAchine -recurse  |
select  @{Name="{#CERTINFO}"; Expression={($_.FriendlyName)}} |
Sort "{#CERTINFO}"

write-host "{"
write-host " `"data`":`n"

convertto-json $cert_days 

write-host
write-host "}"
```

I can't exclude Nulls or empty items like " ".

Using  `-ne $Null` i get boolean results like true or false...

I would appreciate to hear Yours advice how to eliminate nulls or empty entries

Comment: You have a slightly problematic property name with ```{#CertInfo}```, but I'm assuming you really want that name. Otherwise, if you don't feel strongly about the ```{#CertInfo}``` property name, your code would probably be easier to write and read if you change the ```Select``` to ```Select FriendlyName``` or similar, instead.

Comment: I need #CERTINFO for Zabbix Low Level Discovery rules : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude empty entries, you could add a filter to remove those, preferably before the `Sort-Object` call., e.g.

```
$certs = ls Cert:\LocalMachine\ -Recurse |
    Select @{Name = '{#CertInfo}'; Expression = {$_.FriendlyName}} |
    Where { $_.'{#CertInfo}' } |
    Sort '{#CertInfo}'
```

Comment: Work like a charm! : )))

Answer (score 0):

[Robert Westerlund's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729660/45375) shows one way of filtering out `$null` and `''` (empty-string) values, using the `Where-Object` cmdlet, which coerces the output from the script block to a Boolean, causing both `$null` and `''` evaluate to `$False` and thus causing them to be filtered out.

This answer shows an alternative approach and discusses other aspects of the question.

---

**tl;dr**:

```sh
@{ 
  data = @((Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine).FriendlyName) -notlike '' |
           Sort-Object | Select-Object @{ n='{#CERTINFO}'; e={ $_ } }
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

---

> Using  `-ne $Null` i get boolean results like true or false...

**You only get a *Boolean* if the LHS is a *scalar* rather than an *array*** - in the case of an array, the *matching array elements* are returned.

To **ensure that the LHS (or any expression or command output) is an array, wrap it in `@(...)`** the *array-subexpression operator* (the following uses PSv3+ syntax ):

```sh
@((Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine).FriendlyName) -notlike ''
```

Note the **use of `-notlike ''` to weed out both `$null` and `''` values**: `-notlike` forces the LHS to a *string*, and `$null` is converted to `''`.

By contrast, if you wanted to use `-ne $null`, you'd have to use `-ne ''` *too* so as to also eliminate empty strings (though, in this particular case you could get away with *just* `-ne ''`, because `ConvertTo-Json` would simply ignore `$null` values in its input).

Calling `.FriendlyName` on the typically array-valued output of `Get-ChildItem` directly is a PSv3+ feature called [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375): the `.FriendlyName` property access is applied to *each element* of the array, and the results are returned as a new array.

Filtering and sorting the values *before* constructing the wrapper objects with the `{#CERTINFO}` property not only simplifies the command, but is also more efficient.

Further thoughts:

- **[Do not use `Write-Host` to output *data*](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)**: `Write-Host` bypasses PowerShell's (success) output stream; instead, use `Write-Output`, which you rarely need to call explicitly however, because its use is *implied*.

  - Instead of `write-host "{"`, use `write-output "{"` or - preferably - simply `"{"` by itself.
- **PowerShell supports multi-line strings** (see [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1)), so there's no need to output the result line by line:

  ```sh
    @"
    {
      "data":
       $(<your ConvertTo-Json pipeline>)
    }
    "@
  ```
- However, given that you're invoking `ConvertTo-Json` anyway, it's simpler to **provide the `data` wrapper as a *PowerShell* object** (in the simplest form as a hashtable) **to `ConvertTo-Json`**, as shown above.